# How I create installable package of desktop projects as single setup

Tags: asp.net, release, setup-project, windows

I have created desktop application wherein there are  three projects include. any one can give me idea to create installable setup in visual studio 2008

[image]

& i feel second problem with

[image]

Comment: I am getting error on build, "An error occurred while validating. HRESULT = '80004005'"

Comment: My application is having WPF implemented in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create setup project in visual studio 2008

[image: Setup Project]

Check this http://balanagaraj.wordpress.com/2007/05/29/create-exe-or-setup-file-in-net-windows-application/

Comment: @Nitin : it shows Error An error occurred while validating. HRESULT

Comment: In Visual studio go to File => New Project => Select "Setup Project" from the list  [@MayP](http://stackoverflow.com/users/554828/mayp)

Comment: @Nitin: tell me what is to be added in Application Folder ? Primary output/source files....? "An error occurred while validating.  HRESULT = '80004005'"

Comment: yup, in Application folder you can add Primary Output of the project

Comment: @Nitin: then it shows me above error when i start "build". any tactful procedure needed? I am having three projects in one solution

Comment: If you have more than one projects then you should add primary output from all of them to the application folder, Check this [tutorial](http://parassanghani.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-create-setup-project-in-vs-2008.html)